ICS calendar RRULE not applied
I am working with some ICS files containing recurring series of events.
Initially, I generated one ICS file for these events and successfully imported them into Outlook.
However, when I extended the series by four more days and generated a new file, importing it into Outlook did not update my calendar.
Why is this happening? What could be wrong?
Initial file:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Meeting Maker//Scheduler MIMEDIR//EN VERSION:2.0 METHOD:REQUEST BEGIN:VTIMEZONE TZID:GMT Standard Time BEGIN:STANDARD DTSTART:16011027T020000 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10 TZOFFSETFROM:+0100 TZOFFSETTO:+0000 END:STANDARD BEGIN:DAYLIGHT DTSTART:16010331T010000 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3 TZOFFSETFROM:+0000 TZOFFSETTO:+0100 END:DAYLIGHT END:VTIMEZONE BEGIN:VEVENT ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:local@acs.local ORGANIZER;CN="Scheduler":MAILTO:local@acs.local DTSTART;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20240415T023000 DTEND;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20240415T033000 FREEBUSY;FBTYPE=BUSY:20240415T013000Z/20240415T023000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240422T023000Z;INTERVAL=1 CATEGORIES:Scheduler RESOURCES:Tst; LOCATION:7th Heaven; ShambalaGroup; Tst TRANSP:OPAQUE SUMMARY:oran UID:-1999997636 DTSTAMP:20240417T120700Z DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:http://localhost/res/Res.asp?ID=-1999997636 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:Action Performed By: oran<br> Meeting Contact : oran, oran@oran.com, <br><br> Reservation Title: oran<br><br> Recur ring Every 1 Day(s) Until Monday, April 22, 2024<br> Date/Time: Monday, A pril 15, 2024 from 02:30 until 03:30 United Kingdom<br> Setup Start: Mond ay, April 15, 2024 02:00 Cleanup End: Monday, April 15, 2024 04:00<br> Lo cation: 7th Heaven; ShambalaGroup; Tst<br><br> <br> Resources: ShambalaGr oup: Tst<br> <br><br> Options:<br> - No Options - <br><br> Recurring Det ails:<br> Apr 15, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 16, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 17, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 18, 2024 , 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 19, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 20, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 21, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br ><br> Apr 22, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br><br><br> Services Details:< br> - None Selected - URL:http://localhost/res/Res.asp?ID=-1999997636 PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
And this is the file which should update my calendar:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Meeting Maker//Scheduler MIMEDIR//EN VERSION:2.0 METHOD:REQUEST BEGIN:VTIMEZONE TZID:GMT Standard Time BEGIN:STANDARD DTSTART:16011027T020000 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10 TZOFFSETFROM:+0100 TZOFFSETTO:+0000 END:STANDARD BEGIN:DAYLIGHT DTSTART:16010331T010000 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3 TZOFFSETFROM:+0000 TZOFFSETTO:+0100 END:DAYLIGHT END:VTIMEZONE BEGIN:VEVENT ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:local@acs.local ORGANIZER;CN="Scheduler":MAILTO:local@acs.local DTSTART;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20240422T023000 DTEND;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20240422T033000 FREEBUSY;FBTYPE=BUSY:20240422T013000Z/20240422T023000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240426T023000Z;INTERVAL=1 CATEGORIES:Scheduler RESOURCES:Tst; LOCATION:7th Heaven; ShambalaGroup; Tst TRANSP:OPAQUE SUMMARY:oran UID:-1999997636 RECURRENCE-ID;TZID="GMT Standard Time":20240422T023000 DTSTAMP:20240417T120800Z DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:http://localhost/res/Res.aspID=-1999997629 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:Action Performed By: oran<br> Meeting Contact : oran, oran@oran.com, <br><br> Reservation Title: oran<br><br> Recur ring Every 1 Day(s) Until Friday, April 26, 2024<br> Date/Time: Monday, A pril 22, 2024 from 02:30 until 03:30 United Kingdom<br> Setup Start: Mond ay, April 22, 2024 02:00 Cleanup End: Monday, April 22, 2024 04:00<br> Lo cation: 7th Heaven; ShambalaGroup; Tst<br><br> <br> Resources: ShambalaGr oup: Tst<br> <br><br> Options:<br> - No Options - <br><br> Recurring Det ails:<br> Apr 15, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 16, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 17, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 18, 2024 , 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 19, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 20, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 21, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br ><br> Apr 22, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 23, 2024, 02:30 - 03:3 0 Tst<br><br> Apr 24, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 25, 2024, 02: 30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br> Apr 26, 2024, 02:30 - 03:30 Tst<br><br><br><br> Services Details:<br> - None Selected - URL:http://localhost/res/Res.asp?ID=-1999997629
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
